# How does $ \left({(n+1)}^4 \over 4^{n+1}\right)\left(4^n \over n^4 \right) $ simplify?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ \left({(n+1)}^4 \over 4^{n+1}\right)\left(4^n \over n^4 \right) $$

Just not sure how this is able to simplify any more.

Comment: Hint: $4^{n+1}=4^n \cdot 4$

Comment: As you can see from the answers, the idea is to group the factors with the same base, or that carry the same exponent, together, and then work with those groups individually as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\dfrac{(n+1)^4}{4^{n+1}} \cdot \dfrac{4^n}{n^4} = \dfrac{4^n}{4^{n+1}} \cdot \dfrac{(n+1)^4}{n^4} = \dfrac14 \cdot \left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^4$$

Comment: How does 4^n/4^(n+1)  simplify to 1/4?

Comment: @Jay $\dfrac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b} = \dfrac1{x^{b-a}}$

Comment: @Jay Look up your index laws. $\frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}} = 4^{n-(n+1)} = 4^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

It is $$\frac14\left(1+\frac1n\right)^4$$